# Password and Numeric Hint for Blackberry (java)

Tags: blackberry, passwords, numeric

Creating a Blackberry app.

Just a beginner, I have searched but couldn't find a solution for it though its common. If anyone could tell me how to show a password hint and a numeric hint for blackberry applications in Java.
Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
According to your query , you want a field that shows password hint and a numeric hint for blackberry applications ..

Well blackberry follow some different way , it will not show hint (PopUp Screen). Another way is to put some (information) Text in the [EditField][1] when EditField is empty .Here is the sample code for demonstration :-

*******************************************************
    EditField _userName_edtField = new EditField()
        {
            protected void layout(int width, int height) 
            {
                super.layout(width, height);
                setExtent(150, height);
            };
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
            {
                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);


                if(isFocus())
                {
                    if(getTextLength() == 0)
                    {
                        setCursorPosition(0);   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(getTextLength() == 0)
                    {
                        graphics.drawText("User Name", 0, (getHeight() - getFont().getHeight()) >>1);   
                    }
                }


                invalidate();

                super.paint(graphics);
            }
        };

                add(_userName_edtField);

*******************************************************

this is Just a simple EditField , you can customize the field according to your requirement  if this is empty it will show "User Name"  and if you enter some text the "User Name" will disappear ..
means the EditField is act like a Hint and this will help you ..!!!


  [1]: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad to get a specific answer but judging by what I believe is that you are talking about a label just above or below the text field to let user know what does the field requires. In this case you can provide a confirmation screen where user is shown the field requirement like field cannot be blank, or the field can only contain numeric values, etc.

You can store the password hint on the device database and when the user enters it wrong get the label field added on the screen displaying it as hint.

Something like this:

```
String storedPassword = ApplicationDAO.getStoredPassword();
        if(!enteredPassword.equals(storedPassword)){
           LabelField hintField = new LabelField();
           hintField.setText("Your hint");
           mainBody.add(hintField);
        }
```

Comment: In simple words I want to display "Password" in the password text field. And when on focus it disappears. Right now Im giving it a password watermark/hint but it is displaying it as ********. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ahmad Shahwaiz, this comment is more clear than the actual question itself. You can add this comment on your question. You can solve your problem using a boolean flag, and overriding the `paint` method of the PasswordEditField. If you need more information, you can reply on this comment.